Adobe DRM not getting acsm files for image pdf
I have an sample image pdf which I want to get drm'ed from adobe, for normal pdf adobe drm does work superbly.
Please find link https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/cguwslagkh0mol4q5oh0m/sample_image_pdf.pdf?rlkey=s6vrnlrc9ac89jjnfd0w32hyn&st=dlj16950&dl=0  sample image pdf. How can I solve this problem?

Adobe ACSM files are simply links to ordinary files such as ePub or pdf, it is simply a URL request much like any hyperlink cookie for a web based document.

An ACSM file (Adobe Content Server Message) is a file that contains information about your book - It is not the book itself.

This is an ASCM from Adobes own Adobe Digital Editions.
<fulfillmentToken fulfillmentType="free" auth="user" xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/adept">
  <distributor>urn:uuid:b4e1303f-630f-4769-9c82-4dea6d65a277</distributor>
  <operatorURL>https://contentserver.adobe.com/fulfillment</operatorURL>
  <transaction>3c78d0be-808b-41f8-8f52-eb4e7c6abb3d-000036d1</transaction>
  <purchase>2024-04-24T21:17:44+00:00</purchase>
  <expiration>2024-04-24T22:17:44+00:00</expiration>
  <resourceItemInfo>
    <resource>urn:uuid:c0385b71-bcd6-44dd-9a69-ec8a931d25e2</resource>
    <resourceItem>1</resourceItem>
    <metadata>
      <dc:title xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">Death and the Senator</dc:title>
      <dc:creator xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">Arthur C. Clarke</dc:creator>
      <dc:publisher xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">RosettaBooks</dc:publisher>
      <dc:identifier xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">0-7953-0690-3</dc:identifier>
      <dc:format xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">application/epub+zip</dc:format>
      <dc:language xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">en-us</dc:language>
    </metadata>
    <licenseToken>
      <resource>urn:uuid:c0385b71-bcd6-44dd-9a69-ec8a931d25e2</resource>
      <permissions>
        <display/>
        <excerpt/>
        <print/>
        <play/>
      </permissions>
    </licenseToken>
  </resourceItemInfo>
  <hmac>IH3RkTAd5wwPTgtUgLPUjSz43uk=</hmac>
</fulfillmentToken>

So the book does not have to include any DRM. Even if it does Adobe DRM is designed to be used in Adobe software like ADE or Acrobat, and does not need to be respected by other 3rd parties. Once downloaded the document can be copied into other devices and software including editors.
It is best not to use PDF DRM since:
A) it does not protect a document from changes once opened.
B) There are increasing cases of class action, due to the restrictions DRM places on those already challenged by in-accessibility to web published data.
The challenge in the legal system by converting text to images is mentioned in the 2020 image only quoted example. (Converted below to be "Accessible" in Adobe Acrobat or any other reader.)
So the first task with such files is ensure they are readable by the short of sight or blind. There are many PDF image to PDF text converters to make that easier for you, even without installation.

The sample file now has improved Digital Rights added for accessibility Management of image reading by the blind. I have not added PDF/Accessibility features but anybody can manage those.

